# How to reduce a if statements?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an object that has the result of a query, this object has date's fields and I need to deal where the field has the date '01-01-1991' change to null. How can I simplify this if statement?

```cs
if(item.date01 == "01-01-1991")
   item.date01 = null;

if(item.date02 == "01-01-1991")
   item.date02 = null;

if(item.date03 == "01-01-1991")
   item.date03 = null;

if(item.date04 == "01-01-1991")
   item.date04 = null;
```

I tried to use `foreach`, but didn't know how...

```cs
foreach(var item in items)
{
    if(item.obj == "01-01-1991")
      item.obj = null;
}
```

Comment: Please provide *actual* code instead of pseudo-code, ideally in the form of a [mcve]. The right answer for this sort of thing is almost always to avoid numbered fields/properties like this, and use a collection instead.

Comment: Why are you storing dates in a string field?

Answer (score 3):

Because you want to compare each property with a constant string, you can use this code:

```
foreach (var item in items.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (item.GetValue(items).ToString() == "01-01-1991") 
        item.SetValue(items, null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you have a working example, since the single quotes in `'01-01-1991' are not valid to use in a string or datetime.

Also, you mention that the date01, date02, ... are **fields**. In that case, you can do the following:

```
var item = new DataItem();

void CheckAndSet(ref string? date)
{
    if (date == "01-01-1900")
    {
        date = null;
    }
}

CheckAndSet(ref item.date01);
CheckAndSet(ref item.date02);
CheckAndSet(ref item.date03);
CheckAndSet(ref item.date04);

public class DataItem
{
    public string? date01;
    public string? date02;
    public string? date03;
    public string? date04;
}
```

To elaborate, you can use the `ref` keyword to keep the reference to the original variable, which in this case is the date0x field in the DataItem class.

Comment: @DStanley Thanx, I mentioned that explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

iterate each item of items

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
    this.CheckAndSetDate(ref item.date01,"01-01-1991");
    this.CheckAndSetDate(ref item.date02,"01-01-1991");
    this.CheckAndSetDate(ref item.date03,"01-01-1991");
    this.CheckAndSetDate(ref item.date04,"01-01-1991");
}
```

then create validate function

```
public void CheckAndSetDate(ref string date, string value)
{
   date = date == value ? null : date;
}
```

or

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
    item.date01 = this.CheckAndSetDate(item.date01,"01-01-1991");
    item.date02 = this.CheckAndSetDate(item.date02,"01-01-1991");
    item.date03 = this.CheckAndSetDate(item.date03,"01-01-1991");
    item.date04 = this.CheckAndSetDate(item.date04,"01-01-1991");
}

public string CheckAndSetDate(ref string date, string value)
{
   return date == value ? null : date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reflection.

```
foreach(var element in (IEnumerable)item)
     {
          Type type = element.GetType();
          PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
          foreach(PropertyInfo p in properties)
          {
              if(p.GetValue(element,null) == "01-01-1991")
              {
                  p.SetValue(item, null, null)
              }

           } 
      }
```